# elasticdump started from with bash from crontab does not dump all records

Tags: bash, cron

I have an elasticdump command in a bash file

```
#!/bin/bash

elasticdump \
  --input=url would be here/datalayer \
  --output=weownit_data/datalayer_now.json \
  --searchBody '{"query": {"filtered": {"query": {
    "match_all" : {}},"filter": {"bool": {"must": [{"numeric_range": {"timestamp": {"gte": 1434499493}}},{"type" : {"value" : "event2"}}]}}}}}'
```

The command works normally if I run it by itself. The bash file works normally if I run it by itself, both of these download 200,000 records.

My crontab looks like the following

```
0 2 * * * /home/woibasic/projects/all_since_jun172015.bash > /home/woibasic/projects/logging/elasticsearch.log
```

When I look at elasticsearch.log it shows the following

```
Fri, 26 Jun 2015 02:00:02 GMT | starting dump
Fri, 26 Jun 2015 02:00:02 GMT | got 100 objects from source elasticsearch (offset: 0)
```

So the question really is, why is it stopping at 100 objects, it seems like cron is shutting down too soon for some reason.

Comment: The crontab is for the same user as you tested the script, right? --- Does not elasticdump and/or Node.js require some environment variables to work as expected?

Comment: well elasticdump is set globally so I don't think that is right, should be the same user, but I think, yeah hmm it's maybe a rights issue - like elasticdump is existing because it doesn't have rights to output the objects it got from elasticsearch to the output file. although normally I would expect a message about that in output.'

Comment: If you edited the crontab using `crontab -e` started under the user then it is the user's crontab and cron will run commands as the user. - - - - - - Regarding environment variables I would recommend: - - - **1.** list variables in the functional environment (where the script works): `export`. - - - **2.** Run a shell with empty environment: `exec -c bash --norc --noprofile`. - - - **3.** Try to run your script there. If it does not work export the variables from 1. in the script. - - - **4.** If it does work with the exported variables you can test one by one to find the required ones.

Comment: I also have this issue, have you found something in the meantime?